# Sorting things out after an ESXi crash

Tags: vmware-esxi, server-crashes

I have recently experienced some crashes on my ESXi server, and I cant really figure out why it is happening.

Are there any logs that are useful anywhere?

I have read somewhere on the internet that the host itself should have assigned between 256-800MB RAM, but in my case it is only assigned 77MB.
- Are there any way to increase that?

I am running ESXi5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default logs are kept in /scratch/log on the host, but depending on where ESXi is installed they may not persist through reboots. You can enable SSH on the host to get in there and examine the logs. If they aren't persisting, you can either configure ESXi to forward to an external log host or create a persistent scratch location as per [this article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1033696).

Comment: Thanks - found some logs there. Any clue which file to look in?

Comment: I'd start with vmkernel.log. There's also an overview of files and their contents at http://vninja.net/virtualization/vmware-esxi-4-vs-esxi-5-log-file-locations/ .